# $a_n$ is convergent, $b_n$ bounded, prove $\sum a_n b_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is a convergent series with $a_n$ > $0$ and suppose that $(b_n){_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}$ is a bounded sequence of positive numbers. Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n b_n$ is convergent.

Since $b_n$ is bounded and $b_n$ > $0$, can we conclude that there exists M > $0$ such that $0$ < $b_n$ < M or only that $b_n$ > $0$?
If we cannot conclude that $b_n$ < M then how can we answer this question?

Comment: Yes you can conclude $0<b_n<M$.  That is precisely what it means for a sequence of positive numbers to be bounded.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So then we can say that $\sum a_n b_n$ < $\sum a_n M$ = M$\sum a_n$ and therefore by the comparison test $\sum a_n b_n$ is convergent?

Comment: In fact all we need is the upper bound $M\sum a_n<+\infty$ and $\sum a_nb_n\nearrow$ which happens as $a_nb_n\ge 0$.

Comment: @DuncanRamage can we not assume the first inequality because it is stated that $a_n$ > $0$ and $b_n$ > $0$?

Answer (score 3):

Since $(b_n)$ is bounded and positive, there is an $M\geq b_n >0$ for alle $n\in\mathbb{N}$.By the direct comparision test we have:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nb_n\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cdot M=M\underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n}_{<\infty}<\infty$

Comment: @DuncanRamage It's mentioned in the post that $b_n$ are positive.

Comment: I actualy do not see, why this would "prove" that non-convergent series converge. What has to be repaired?

Comment: @Cornman I misread the question and didn't see that the an are positive. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^ma_kb_k\right|\leq\sum_{k=n+1}^m|a_kb_k|\leq M \sum_{k=n+1}^m|a_k|\to0
$$
as $m,n\to\infty$.